# That username is taken

Tags: gmail, google-account

When trying to log into my gmail account on my PC, I get the error message "That username is taken."
But I know as a fact, that the user name is the name I registered.
As a matter of fact on my Android phone I am still logged in into that very same adress.
How can I log in?

Comment: Are you using the full address? Try that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are clicking on the 'Create account' link, rather than simply entering your email address.  The 'Create account' doesn't refer to creating an account on your PC but rather creating a brand new Gmail email account (address).

### Links that may help:

1. [Direct link to Sign In to Gmail](https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail)
2. [How to Sign in to Gmail on your PC](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8494?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop)